# git clone Error: ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Tags: ssh, port

gitlab9.3.9 upgrade to 11.9, git pull OR git clone don't work

My surroundings:
docker-compose.yaml

```
web:
   image: 'gitlab-ce:11.9.1-ce.0'  
   container_name: gitlab_web
   restart: always
   hostname: 'gitlabweb'
   environment:
     GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url 'http://cicd.poc.com:8081'
        gitlab_rails['time_zone'] = 'Asia/Shanghai'  
        gitlab_rails['admin_email_worker_cron'] = "0 0 * 0 *"
        gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 8081
    nginx['listen_port'] = 8081 
   ports:
     - '8081:8081'
   volumes:
     - './git_data:/var/opt/gitlab'
     - './gitconfig:/etc/gitlab'
     - './git_log:/var/log/gitlab'
```

Try in my client PC OR Server's container(gitlab_web) :
Re-created my ssh keys and rm ~/.ssh/known_hosts , but git pull OR clone problem still exists:

```
$ git clone ssh://git@cicd.poc.com:8081/poc/53.git
Cloning into '53'...
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Ask for help

Comment: Or don't setup gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 8081, client PC still this problem

Answer (score 0):

fix:
Server work:
1. change Gitlab server host SSH port from 22 to 222 and restart ssh service

```
$vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
$/etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

2. docker-compose.yaml add ssh port 22

```
ports:
  - '8081:8081'
  - '22:22'
```

3. docker-compose down
4. docker-compose up -d

Client work:

```
delete ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```